# React js ERROR in ./node_modules/jwt-simple/lib/jwt.js 13:13-30

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/jwt-simple/lib/jwt.js 13:13-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/shikhapandey/Desktop/Control_Plane/control-plane-ui/node_modules/jwt-simple/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
- install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }

Answer (score 0):

Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/jwt-simple/lib/jwt.js 13:13-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/shikhapandey/Desktop/CPU/control-plane-ui/node_modules/jwt-simple/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
- install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is contained in the error:

> - install 'crypto-browserify'
> - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }' [to your Webpack config]